# Data Extract Widget in flex viewer 3.6 does not contain output data

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-flex-viewer, widget

I am currently trying to configure a map service with flexviewer 3.6 on ArcServer 10.2. I have already published my .mxd file as a map service and it displays correctly in my flexviewer application. 
Now I want to use the extract data widget to download specified feature layers. The widget works fine and it downloads the .zip file, but it does not contain any data. Did I configured my map service correctly or what's the underlying problem?

I have already read the related questions and the help section of Esri, but I have not found an answer yet.

This is the relevant part of my config.xml file:

```
    <operationallayers>
        <layer type="dynamic" label="Thermochronology Kyrgyz Tien Shan" imageformat="png8" url="http://MYSERVERIP/arcgis/rest/services/Kyrgyzstan_Geochronology_TEST/Thermochronology_Kyrgyz_Tien_Shan/MapServer" visible="true"/>
    </operationallayers>
</map>
<widgetcontainer layout="float">
    <widget url="widgets/DataExtract/DataExtractWidget.swf" config="widgets/DataExtract/DataExtractWidget_1.xml" label="Datenextraktion" icon="assets/images/i_scissors.png"/>
</widgetcontainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK,now I solved the problem by my own, but for others who have a similar problem:

My problem was that I used the sample geoprocessing service which was enabled by default. To overcome this problem one has to publish the "extract data task" tool from arcmap to the server first. After that, one has to replace the sample geoprocessing service with the URL of the own geoprocessing service in the xml file of the extract data widget.

A more detailed description is given in the following ESRI Tutorial:
http://video.arcgis.com/watch/861/data-extraction-services-in-arcgis-server-10